# What am I doing wrong - using a pre-defined PDF form (using Apache PDFBox), copying pages?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

So I have a pre-designed PDF form (it is a medical billing form).  It contains many fields and I fill them out with data from my application - using Apache PDFBox.  This is no problem and it works fine.

The issue comes when there are more than 6 items on the bill - then I need to make a copy of the first page, and fill it out all over with the remaining items - repeat if there are more than 12 - etc.

One would think it would be easy - just reopen the template PDF with `Loader.loadPdf()` to reset the form - fill in the data for page X - add that page to the output PDF - and good.  That didn't work.

So now what I'm doing is making a totally separate output PDF for each page - and those DO generate correctly - and then going back and making a new "merged" output PDF from those separate ones.

It doesn't generate correctly.  Page 1 looks totally fine but page 2 ends up looking like this:

[incorrectly rendered page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5pxB.png)

For reference page 2 actually looks like this:

[correct render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RPiF.png)

I'm generating the final output PDF by just looping through the separate page ones, using `importPage()` to import the page and then saving.  I've no idea at all why it doesn't work, even though the individual page ones are completely correct.

Any pointers on how to do this properly?

I'm at a loss here.  Any pointers/ideas/etc would be much appreciated.

Comment: It’s really hard to suggest changes to code we cannot see.  Edit your question and include the code that generates the pages with the items on them (as text, please, not as an image).

Comment: Does it work if you are using 2.0.*? (Use `PDDocument.load()` to open a document)

Comment: Have the field names on the extra pages been changed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KJ if the op had actually filled in a pure xfa, they surely would have mentioned that (as it is not directly supported by pdfbox). Thus, I assume it's either a plain AcroForm version or a hybrid one (of which they filled the AcroForm part only). And by extra pages I meant those they added using `importPage()`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr - Yes, downgrading to 2.0.30 makes it all work as expected.  I'm...actually ok with that.

Comment: @VGR - the code is rather long and since I've been at this a while trying to get it to work, is pretty darn ugly. :D  But Tilman Hausherr's suggestion of trying with 2.x ... made it all work.  So I think I'll go with that and call it good.  If you'd like to see the code, though, let me know.  I don't think posting it in the post makes since but I could send it to you privately.

Comment: PDFBox 3.0.* has some nasty bugs involving splitting, joining, or inserting stuff from "foreign" PDFs. Some have been fixed in the current snapshot, but not all. I suggest you retry when the next 3.0.* version is released, and if it still doesn't work, please create an issue in PDFBox JIRA. (be careful to mention something specific if registering an account, or we'll assume you're a spammer)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr - Thank you so much for the concise and simple answer.  I'll watch the releases and try again in a while.  For now, 2.x is fine; I just need to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

When working with official forms (especially Government Approved) you should only use authorised copies not unofficial sample images, especially ones 12 years ago and many revisions since.

Here are the 173 field placements for the [official authorised Form 1500](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/owcp/FECA/regs/compliance/forms). A STATIC XFA should work in browsers, however note the warnings. Approved version 2015-06 revised 2019-06 and 2021-10 Expires 2024-06. Includes pulldowns, JavaScript actions and official print button for official email submission. As such it can be bulk filled using FDF files. It must not be merged.

[image]

Warnings include

- Print the form (use the Print button on or near the top of the form), authorize the form (if applicable provide hand-written signature) and mail or fax the completed form to the Federal Employees Program office you normally send to for this process.
- Please contact your agency if you have questions about filling these forms or need other forms. You can also use Contact Us to reach your agency for assistance. **NOTE: When printing these files please remember to use the Adobe Acrobat Reader print icon or the [Print] button on the form, itself, and NOT your browser's print icon** on the browser toolbar.